# unable to change image in a div through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    function light() {
      if (document.getElementById("push").value == "OFF") {
        document.getElementById("bulb").style.backgroundImage = url("1.png");
        document.getElementByID("push").value = "ON";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("bulb").style.backgroundImage = url("2.png");
        document.getElementByID("push").value = "OFF";
      }
    }
  </script>
  <center>
    <input type="button" id="push" onclick="light()" value="OFF" />
    <div id="bulb" style="background-image:url(2.png);width:320px;height:420px">
    </div>enter code here
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: javascript != java.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting and removed the irrelevant tags, but as this is your *third* question, I would expect that you would be formatting at least minimally by now.

Comment: Be careful with your capitalization - `getElementById` is not the same as `getElementByID`

Comment: Thanks PeterLawrey . I'm new here so it will take a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
document.getElementById("bulb").style.backgroundImage = url("1.png");
```

attempts to call a function called `url` and pass a string to it, and then assign the result of that to the `backgroundImage` property.

Instead, you want to assign a *string* to `backgroundImage` directly:

```
document.getElementById("bulb").style.backgroundImage = "url(1.png)";
// Note ------------------------------------------------^----^----^^
```

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("bulb").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-qJYMzFfIels/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGM/16Ir8NxI3gE/photo.jpg?sz=32)";
```

```html
<div id="bulb" style="width: 32px; height: 32px"></div>
```

---

That said, it would be better to define your styling and such in CSS and then associate those styles with elements using selectors, for instance via a class association:

CSS:

```
.class-saying-what-the-image-represents {
    background-image: url(1.png);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("bulb").classList.add("class-saying-what-the-image-represents");
```

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("bulb").classList.add("class-saying-what-the-image-represents");
```

```css
.class-saying-what-the-image-represents {
    background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-qJYMzFfIels/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGM/16Ir8NxI3gE/photo.jpg?sz=32);
}
```

```html
<div id="bulb" style="width: 32px; height: 32px"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible that div has both an id and a class?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari: Of course (the `div` in my second example does, for instance, once the code has run). It can also have multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder !